# Running SAGA tools from Pycharm standalone QGIS (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, saga, standalone, pycharm

I am trying to run SAGA through the Python interface of QGIS. So far I have worked with only Native QGIS, and below code works for native. I would like to use SAGA fromout the same script, but am getting an `_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm sagang:splitlineswithlines not found` exception.

```
import sys

from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.extend(['/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing',
                 '/usr/share/qgis/python', '/usr/lib/qgis/plugins',
                 '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/',  # Added this to try
                 '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'  # Added this to try
                 ])
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Processing.initialize()

T = processing.run("sagang:splitlineswithlines",
                   {
                       'LINES': '/file/one',
                       'SPLIT': '/file/two',
                       'INTERSECT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
                       'OUTPUT': 1
                   })
```

SAGA works fine fromout the QGIS gui.

I have tried:

`Processing.updateAlgsList()` -- Doesnt exist anymore

`processing.runalg` -- doesnt exist either.

Running:
Ubuntu 20.04
QGIS 3.26.3-Buenos Aires
SAGA Version: 7.3.0

Anyone any suggestion as to why my Python can't find the SAGA tool?

Comment: For differences in the QGIS GUI and a standalone interpreter, for me it usually boils down to where the interpreter is pointing, which python installation is being called. How many QGIS installations do you have?  When Python runs on the interpreter, can you confirm it's the right Python install?  I am on Windows, so I might not have much insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue when running saga tools with PyQGIS in spyder. Problem come from paths assignement.

I followed this tutorial and works for me! I'm under windows 10, QGIS 3.24, python 3.9 --> https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-qgis-spatial-algorithms-with-python-scripts-4bf980e39898
I recommend to follow it for more informations but the main steps are:

**Step 1: Fetch and Export System Paths & OS Environment Variables from QGIS Python Console**

Open the **QGIS Desktop app and open the Python console**. Then run the following lines first to export system paths and environment variables to a CSV file.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import os
import json

# export system paths to a CSV file
paths = sys.path
df = pd.DataFrame({'paths':paths})
df.to_csv('<PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT_THIS_FILE>/qgis_sys_paths.csv', index=False)

# export the environment variables
env = dict(os.environ)
rem = ['SECURITYSESSIONID', 'LaunchInstanceID', 'TMPDIR']
_ = [env.pop(r, None) for r in rem]
with open('<PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT_THIS_FILE>/qgis_env.json', 'w') as f:
   json.dump(env, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

**Step 2: Init QGIS libraries in Python Script before using its Algorithms**

Before you can use the QGIS libraries and their spatial algorithms in your python script, we need to set up the environment variables and paths we just exported. Also, we need to initialise the processing module of the QGIS.

**Do this at the start of your script in Pycharm (spyder for me):**

```
# necessary imports
import os
import sys
import json
import pandas as pd

# set up system paths
qspath = '<PATH_WHERE_IS_YOUR_FILE>/qgis_sys_paths.csv' 

# provide the path where you saved this file.
paths = pd.read_csv(qspath).paths.tolist()
sys.path += paths

# set up environment variables
qepath = '<PATH_WHERE_IS_YOUR_FILE>/qgis_env.json'
js = json.loads(open(qepath, 'r').read())
for k, v in js.items():
    os.environ[k] = v
    
# In special cases, we might also need to map the PROJ_LIB to handle the projections
# for mac OS
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = '/Applications/Qgis.app/Contents/Resources/proj'

# qgis library imports
import PyQt5.QtCore
# import gdal  # This import doesn't work for me but you don't need it for process saga tools
import qgis.PyQt.QtCore
from qgis.core import (QgsApplication,
                       QgsProcessingFeedback,
                       QgsProcessingRegistry)
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

# initializing processing module
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(js['HOME'], True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis() # use qgs.exitQgis() to exit the processing module at the end of the script.

# initialize processing algorithms
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

# Check QGIS algorithms you can use now
algs = dict()
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    algs[alg.displayName()] = alg.id()
print(algs)

# Try a saga tool
# clip DEM with polygon
processing.run('saga:cliprasterwithpolygon', 
               {'INPUT':path_dem,
                'OUTPUT':path_output,
                'POLYGONS':path_polygon,
                'EXTENT':1})

# Don't forget to exit the processing module at the end of the script
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Saga tool that I use from the QGIS Python Console.  There are some extra imports and steps needed to run from PyCharm, but I'm not up on that.

```
processing.run(
                "saga:resampling",
                {'INPUT':
                    [item_input[1]],
                    'OUTPUT':os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER,os.path.basename(item_input[1].split(".")[0])+"_"+item_input[0]+'.sdat'),
                    'KEEP_TYPE':False,
                    'SCALE_UP':0,
                    'SCALE_DOWN':0,
                    'TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX':None,
                    'TARGET_USER_SIZE':30}
            )
```

The trick is to run it once from the GUI, and then go to the Processing History, copy the code from there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, howeever, this doesnt solve my problem. I know the syntax of the script is fine, as I generated it from the GUI through "Advanced..." -> Copy to Python command. Which is similar to how you suggest to do it. My question is indeed more on IDE configuration: What to do when GUI execution is fine, but from Pycharm gives an " Algorithm not found" exception.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a bit but I finally found a working solution for Ubuntu. It imports SAGA Next Gen to the current Python instance and adds its provider to QGIS' processingRegistry.

```
# QGIS INIT
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/')
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
import processing
processing.core.Processing.Processing.initialize()
# QGIS INIT

# SAGA INIT
sys.path.append('/home/**USER**/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/')
from processing_saga_nextgen.saga_nextgen_plugin import SagaNextGenAlgorithmProvider
provider = SagaNextGenAlgorithmProvider()
provider.loadAlgorithms()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(provider=provider)
# SAGA INIT
```